# MySQL - Transform simple table

Tags: mysql, transform

This seems easy but I have a feeling it may be many steps to achieve. Is there any easy way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for aggregation functions, in particular, `group_concat()`.  The key is that you want to do two aggregations:

```
select subgroupcombo, count(*) as NumCustomers, sum(spend) as TotalSpend,
       sum(Transactions) as TotalTransactions
from (select customer, group_concat(subgroup order by subgroup) as subgroupcombo,
             sum(spend) as spend, sum(transactions) as transactions
      from input i
      group by customer
     ) c
group by subgroupcombo;
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Well played :) group_concat saves the day.

Comment: One slight problem Gordon. I didn't mention this earlier... If Customer A buys again from Sub-Group 1, his combo will be 1,1,2,3,4,5. How do I make the combinations unique? And so that it sums both of those transactions in sub-group 1 together :/

Comment: @Lucas . . . That is actually how this works.  If you wanted to ignore such duplicates, you would add the `distinct` keyword to the `group_concat()`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I might try my luck with one more if you're still online... This could be too much to ask... Is it possible to include a column for each sub group which shows the breakdown of where the spend was between the two sub_groups. E.g. There are 10 sub_group columns and the customer has purchased in 2 and 5. In sub_group columns 2 and 5 their spend will appear. Adding these would be equal to our total.  It's totally fine if this is too complicated. You've made the world of difference already :)

Comment: @Lucas . . . That sounds like another question.

Comment: Haha yes indeed. I'll have a crack myself. Thanks for your help! Lifesaver